# Expend/collapse table rows in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Check the code bellow. My code currently working fine but when I click "More" button its expends all rows and once i click "Less" it collapse all rows. My goal is: by default display only first 6 rows when I click more it will load reset all available rows. Then when I click "Less" it will collapse only the expended rows the 6 rows will be as like default position. And if the rows less then 6 then this button will just not do anything. Also if possible I wanted slow dropdown not slow hide/show.

How can I achieve that?

```js
$(".table").children("tbody").hide();
$("#expendbtn").html("More");
     
$("#expendbtn").click(function(){        
  if ($("#expendbtn").text()=="More") {
    $(".table").children("tbody").show("slow");
    $("#expendbtn").html("Less");
  } else {        
    $(".table").children("tbody").hide("slow");
    $("#expendbtn").html("More");
  }        
});
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
            <table class="table table-striped jambo_table">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="headings">
                        <th><h4>Main Cat</h4></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Sub cat</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Sub cat</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Sub cat</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Sub cat</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Sub cat</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Sub cat</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Sub cat</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Sub cat</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Sub cat</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Sub cat</td>
                    </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="expendbtn"></button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: please provide working fiddle too

Comment: When you say "when i click more it will load reset all available rows", what did you mean by "load"? Load from where? Load what? Thanks.

Comment: Load mean just display nothing complex

Comment: OK @JohnLk (sorry for my bad english). By the way, you'll find my working, shorter and expendable example below. I think you've got your answer, now? ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you.

A simple tweak inside you `script`, I have changed this ↓

```
$(".table").children("tbody").hide();
```

to this ↓

```
$(".table").find("tr").hide().slice(0, 7).show();
```

**A working fiddle for you. ↓**

```js
$(".table").find("tr").hide().slice(0, 7).show();
$("#expendbtn").html("More");

$("#expendbtn").click(function() {

  if ($("#expendbtn").text() == "More") {
    $(".table").find("tr").show();
    $("#expendbtn").html("Less");
  } else {

    $(".table").find("tr").hide().slice(0, 7).show();
    $("#expendbtn").html("More");
  }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>test</title>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <table class="table table-striped jambo_table">
          <thead>
            <tr class="headings">
              <th>
                <h4>Main Cat</h4>
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Sub cat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Sub cat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Sub cat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Sub cat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Sub cat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Sub cat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Sub cat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Sub cat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Sub cat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Sub cat</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="expendbtn"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**Updated 2 with transition**

```js
$(".table").find("tr:nth-child(6)").nextAll().addClass('slideUp');
$("#expendbtn").html("More");

$("#expendbtn").click(function() {

  if ($("#expendbtn").text() == "More") {
    $(".table").find("tr").removeClass('slideUp');
    $("#expendbtn").html("Less");
  } else {

    $(".table").find("tr:nth-child(6)").nextAll().addClass('slideUp');
    $("#expendbtn").html("More");
  }

});
```

```css
.table tbody{
}

.table tr{
 transition: all ease-in-out 0.4s;
 overflow:hidden;
 max-height:100px;
}

.table tr.slideUp{
  transform: scaleY(0);
  display:block;
  max-height:0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>test</title>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <table class="table table-striped jambo_table">
          <thead>
            <tr class="headings">
              <th>
                <h4>Main Cat</h4>
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Sub cat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Sub cat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Sub cat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Sub cat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Sub cat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Sub cat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Sub cat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Sub cat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Sub cat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Sub cat</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="expendbtn"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Nice this is fine but is it possible to make it slow dropdown type animated when its expending and collapsing ?

Comment: Let me see bro.

Comment: @JohnLk check my **updated 2** Answer, hope this was helpfull. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/v5pvxujp/1/

```js
$("#expendbtn")
  .html("More")
  .click(function(){
    if ($("#expendbtn").text()=="More") {
      $('table tr:nth-child(n+7)').fadeIn('slow');
      $("#expendbtn").html("Less");
    } else {
   $('table tr:nth-child(n+7)').fadeOut('slow');
   $("#expendbtn").html("More");
    }
  });
```

```css
.hideRow {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <table class="table table-striped jambo_table">
            <thead>
                <tr class="headings">
                    <th><h4>Main Cat</h4></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="hideRow">
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="hideRow">
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="hideRow">
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="hideRow">
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="expendbtn"></button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Nice this is fine but is it possible to make it slow dropdown type animated when its expending and collapsing ?

Comment: @JohnLk Just give me sometime, will help you. I'm looking into it.

Comment: @JohnLk Check the updated answer. I've used fadeIn & fadeOut.

Answer (score 0):

A working, shorter and expendable example:

```js
  /**
    * Hide every row from +irow+
    * If +animateIt+ is true, animate the dropdown
    *
    */
  function hideRowsStartingAt(irow, animateIt)
  {
    $(".table tbody").children("tr:nth-child(n+"+irow+")").hide(animateIt ? 'slow' : null);
  }

  
  // Set up

  hideRowsStartingAt(7);
  $("#expendbtn").html("More");

  // Wait (for click) and see

  $("#expendbtn").click(function(){
    
    // Collapse or expend ?
    var doExpend = $("#expendbtn").text() == "More" ;

    if ( doExpend ) 
    {
      $(".table tbody").children("tr").show('slow');
    }
    else // doCollapse
    {
      hideRowsStartingAt(7, true);
    }

    // Button name is now…

    $("#expendbtn").html(doExpend ? 'Less' : 'More') ;

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <table class="table table-striped jambo_table">
            <thead>
                <tr class="headings">
                    <th><h4>Main Cat</h4></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sub cat</td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="expendbtn"></button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```